# How to subtract pandas columns for specific groups in a multi-index dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to subtract the average row of every group with it's corresponding sub_column. This implies I need to difference the `Dribbling_Speed_Team_Blue` with `Dribbling_Speed` corresponding to `Best Player Statistics`
Therefore, the final row (`Difference`) will have the following values -

[image]

This is my prior work to generate this dataframe -

I created a multi-index panda dataframe using a nested dictionary -

```
import pandas as pd
nested_dict = {
    'Game':{
    'Basketball': {
        'Player Statistics': {
            'Dribbling_Speed_Team_Blue': {
                'Player_A': 1,
                'Player_B': 3
            },
              'Dribbling_Speed_Team_Red': {
                'Player_A': 2,
                'Player_B': 4
            }
        },
       'Best Player Statistics': {
            'Dribbling_Speed': {
                'Player': 20,
            }
        }

    },

        'Football': {
        'Best Player Statistics': {
            'Kicking_Power': {
                'Player_A': 12,
                'Player_B': 8
            }
        },
       'Player Statistics': {
            'Kicking_Power_Team_Blue': {
                'Player': 40,
            },
            'Kicking_Power_Team_Red': {
                'Player': 40,
            }
        }

    },
    }
}
```

Then I performed the following operations on it -

```
out = pd.json_normalize(nested_dict)
out.columns = out.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)

sum_data = out.groupby(level=[0, 1,2,3], axis = 1).sum()
count_data = out.groupby(level=[0, 1,2,3], axis = 1).count()
result_df = pd.concat([sum_data, count_data], axis=0, keys=['Sum', 'Count'])
result_df.index = result_df.index.droplevel(-1)
result_df.loc['avg'] = result_df.loc['Sum']/result_df.loc['Count']
```

Doing this gave the following result -

[image]

Please let me know if something is unclear. I am quite new to the process and therefore don't know where to start.

Comment: What you want to do would be easier if the levels had a hierarchy. For instance level2 should be `dribbling`/`kicking` and level3 `best_player`/`team_red`/`team_blue`. Don't mix levels together like `dribbling_team_a`

Comment: @mozway I could change the dataformat by modifying the nested dictionary. Are you suggesting to replace the last column heading in this way: `Dribbling_Speed_Team_Red` changes to 2 levels `Dribbling_Speed` and then `Team Red`. I could do that, but I don't see how it'll help. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Do you have it under control how to generate the dictionary?

Comment: @LukasHestermeyer I generate the dictionary from a string file. That's the level of control I have.

Comment: Could you paste a shortened example of such a string file? I am with @mozway on this, that your data format might not be ideal for the task at hand.

Comment: I understand @LukasHestermeyer. Do you think it would be easier to use python/pandas indexing and extract out the values and then compute `Difference`? My end goal is to have a dataframe with the `Difference` row and the hierarchical column headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would try:

```
import pandas as pd

# I am creating classes, just to make it easier for you to add functions to identify the best players.
class Player:
    def __init__(self, team, game):
        self.data = {'team': team, 'game': game}
    
    def get_data(self):
        return self.data
    
class BasketballPlayer(Player):
    def __init__(self, team, dribbling_speed):
        super(BasketballPlayer, self).__init__(team, 'basketball')
        self.data['dribbling_speed'] = dribbling_speed
    
class FootballPlayer(Player):
    def __init__(self, team, kicking_power):
        super(FootballPlayer, self).__init__(team, 'football')
        self.data['kicking_power'] = kicking_power
        
        
# while generating the data, you could do the following, as example:
players = []
players.append(BasketballPlayer('TeamRed', 1).get_data())
players.append(BasketballPlayer('TeamRed', 3).get_data())
players.append(BasketballPlayer('TeamBlue', 2).get_data())
players.append(BasketballPlayer('TeamBlue', 4).get_data())
players.append(BasketballPlayer('BestPlayer', 20).get_data())
players.append(FootballPlayer('BestPlayer', 12).get_data())
players.append(FootballPlayer('BestPlayer', 8).get_data())
players.append(FootballPlayer('TeamRed', 40).get_data())
players.append(FootballPlayer('TeamBlue', 40).get_data())

# now create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(players)


# get the difference
means = df.groupby(['game', 'team']).mean()
means.apply(lambda x: x - means.loc[(x.name[0], 'BestPlayer')], axis=1)
```

This yields:
[image: Result]

This is not in the exact form as you wanted, but gives several advantages regarding computations.

Since I don't know how the string data is being read, I assumed that you could go through the file and generate the players one by one. For that purpose, I prepared the player classes. Once the data is in this form, it is simple to create the differences, as you can simply use `pd.apply` and a `lambda` function.